# why zxing can not decode this qrcode image?

Tags: qr-code, zxing

JavaSE: Exception is "com.google.zxing.NotFoundException"
Can any one help me?

[image: 1]

The version is 3.4.1

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.zxing</groupId>
            <artifactId>javase</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and the java code is there.

```
        BufferedImageLuminanceSource source = new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(image);
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
        Result result;
        Map<DecodeHintType,Object> hints = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.CHARACTER_SET, "utf-8");
        hints.put(DecodeHintType.TRY_HARDER, Boolean.TRUE);
        result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(bitmap, hints);
        return result.getText();
```

The Exception info is :

com.google.zxing.NotFoundException
There is not anything other displayed...

But the following code can not be decoded out，It's really weird

[image: 2]

Almost identical QR codes, one can be decoded but the other cannot be coded`

Answer (score 0):

Use `GenericMultipleBarcodeReader` to read the QR code.

```java
public void decodefile(String filename) {
        // Read an image to BufferedImage
        BufferedImage image = null;
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(new File(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
            return;
        }

        // ZXing
        BinaryBitmap bitmap = null;
        int[] pixels = image.getRGB(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), null, 0, image.getWidth());
        RGBLuminanceSource source = new RGBLuminanceSource(image.getWidth(), image.getHeight(), pixels);
        bitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(source));
            
        MultiFormatReader reader = new MultiFormatReader();  
        GenericMultipleBarcodeReader multiReader = new GenericMultipleBarcodeReader(reader);
        try {
            Result[] zxingResults = multiReader.decodeMultiple(bitmap);
            System.out.println("ZXing result count: " + zxingResults.length);
            if (zxingResults != null) {
                for (Result zxingResult : zxingResults) {
                    System.out.println("Format: " + zxingResult.getBarcodeFormat());
                    System.out.println("Text: " + zxingResult.getText());
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
        } catch (NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        pixels = null;
        bitmap = null;

        if (image != null) {
            image.flush();
            image = null;
        }
    }
```

Here is my results:

```bash
ZXing result count: 1
Format: QR_CODE
Text: https://mp-daily.bookln.cn/q?c=1201M9XUEDE
```